# Is there plans to add Kotlin support for the Spring Tools Suite?

Tags: kotlin, spring-tools-4, spring-kotlin

I want to use Kotlin with the Spring Tools suite plugin for VSCode but it only supports Java (For things like intellisense).

I know I should just use intelliJ and I will for now but I program in a lot of different languages daily and I would like to do all of this from the same tool.

Answer (score 1):

The Spring Tools 4 extension for VSCode does not support Kotlin yet (for the Spring specific tooling). Feel free to comment on https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/163